# The directory where the file will be created

Tags: python-2.7

```
fo=open("a.txt","w+")
```

If I am creating a text file using the python interface. Where will my "a.txt" text file would be located.

fo: file object
Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Will be created in whatever directory the python file is run from, You can use `os.getcwd` to check it, and `os.chdir` to change it.

if you want,you can set specific path to create your file,using following code

```
"C:\\Test"
```